# does facebook design different web pages for mobile and desktops

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to web Dev, but already comfortable with HTML and CSS designed few social network web pages for my project, but I'm confused.

Do I design a mobile web separately from desktop? If yes, is it possible to use php to tell which page to send to a device?

Lastly does Facebook use this method?

Comment: The concept you're probably looking for is called "Responsive Design". Your question isn't about a code issue as much as it is about general programming concepts, so I'd recommend you Google the topic to learn a bit more about it.

Answer (score 0):

They wouldn't be completely different pages but would use breakpoints for different device sizes.

```
@media (min-width:320px)  { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ }
@media (min-width:481px)  { /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ }
@media (min-width:641px)  { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ }
@media (min-width:961px)  { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```

This is an example of the CSS involved. You can find more at https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack. First off this is not the best place to ask this type I would checkout [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) . I am not familiar with the inner workings of facebook but I would assuming since they are a large company that they create mobile sites from scratch for the best user experience. You do not have to create mobile sites from scratch though. You can create a mobile site and desktop site at the same time using [responsive web design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp). This is handled using css and html, so you can do it using php server code or any server code but the php code is not responsible for it. There are many ui frameworks that will help you do this such as [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a different view, depending the device getting the page, you should use a ***responsive framework***, and you don't need to design your page multiple times (e.g. for mobile and desktop)

You can create one of yours or use something like [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com):

> Build responsive, mobile-first projects on the web with the world’s
>   most popular front-end component library.
>
> Bootstrap is an open source toolkit for developing with HTML, CSS, and
>   JS. Quickly prototype your ideas or build your entire app with our
>   Sass variables and mixins, responsive grid system, extensive prebuilt
>   components, and powerful plugins built on jQuery.

Bootstrap works with any language, so even PHP.

Facebook also developed and uses [React](https://reactjs.org).